# need to group data based on `InstanceData` Name property

Tags: c#

I have one `Packet` like below,

```
var dataPacket = new Packet
            {
                Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
                Results = new Result
                {
                    ResultName = "ResultName1",
                    Instances = new List<Instance>
                    {
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "N1", Value = "V1"},
                                new InstanceData{Name = "N2", Value = "V2"}
                            }
                        },
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "N1", Value = "V3"},
                                new InstanceData{Name = "N2", Value = "V4"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Here are the class structures,

```
  public class Packet
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Result Results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string ResultName { get; set; }
        public List<Instance> Instances { get; set; }
    }

    public class Instance
    {
        public string InstanceName { get; set; }
        public List<InstanceData> InstanceDatas { get; set; }
    }

    public class InstanceData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

For above `Packet` I want to spilt this into 2 `Packets` based on `InstanceData` common `Name`

- All `N1` from `InstanceName1` and `InstanceName2` into one packet
- All `N2` from `InstanceName1` and `InstanceName2` into one packet

Packet1 should be like this,

```
var packet1 = new Packet
            {
                Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
                Results = new Result
                {
                    ResultName = "ResultName1",
                    Instances = new List<Instance>
                    {
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "N1", Value = "V1"},
                            }
                        },
                        new Instance
                        {
                            InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                            {
                                new InstanceData{Name = "N1", Value = "V3"},
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

and similarly packet2.

I have tried below, but this will split on `InstanceData` as well and giving 4 packets.

```
var packets = dataPacket.Results
                .Instances
                .SelectMany(x =>
                    x.InstanceDatas.Select(y => new Packet()
                    {
                        Id = dataPacket.Id,
                        Results = new Result()
                        {
                            ResultName = dataPacket.Results.ResultName,
                            Instances = new List<Instance>()
                            {
                                new Instance()
                                {
                                    InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>() {y},
                                    InstanceName = x.InstanceName
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a helper method which finds the possible names as keys and iterate over the keys. Then you build new object instances for each key you are checking. The source code can look like this:

```
private static IList<Packet> SplitByName(Packet packet) {
    IList<string> names = packet.Results.Instances
        .SelectMany(it => it.InstanceDatas)
        .Select(it => it.Name)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
    IList<Packet> result = new List<Packet>();
    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        List<Instance> newInstances = packet.Results.Instances
            .Select(it => new Instance {
                InstanceName = it.InstanceName,
                InstanceDatas = it.InstanceDatas
                    .Where(it => it.Name == name)
                    .ToList()
            })
            .Where(it => it.InstanceDatas.Any())
            .ToList();
        Result newResult = new Result {
            ResultName = packet.Results.ResultName,
            Instances = newInstances
        };
        result.Add(new Packet {
            Id = packet.Id,
            Results = newResult                    
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

For each `name` you are filtering the `InstanceData` instances for each `Instance` object. Depending on your needs you might want to add `.Where(it => it.InstanceData.Any())` so you don't have any "empty" instances.

Comment: Thank and Appreciate @Progman. on the same line I have one more question. Could you please help here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951068/need-to-split-packet-and-distribute-to-the-right-owner-based-on-rule-match