# need to split packet and distribute to the right owner based on rule match

Tags: c#

I need to split a `packet` bases on some Rules and Name which I need to match with different list `NameOwnersBasedOnRule`.

I have a class `NameOwnersBasedOnRule` where I have defined my different set of Rule\Owner for a Name, number of Rule and Owner are NOT fixed for each Name.

```
var nameOwnersBasedOnRule = new List<NameOwnersBasedOnRule>
        {
            new NameOwnersBasedOnRule
            {
                Name = "Name1", Owners = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Rule1", "Owner1"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Rule2", "Owner2"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Rule3", "Owner3")
                }
            },
            new NameOwnersBasedOnRule
            {
                Name = "Name2", Owners = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Rule2", "Owner2")
                }
            },
            new NameOwnersBasedOnRule
            {
                Name = "Name3", Owners = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Rule1", "Owner1"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Rule1", "Owner2"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Rule1", "Owner3")
                }
            }
        };
```

I have list of `packet` and each packet has some `Rule` associates with it and the `Name` is part of nested `InstanceData` and may be repeated for multiple InstanceName. Here is one sample data packet,

```
var dataPacket = new Packet
        {
            Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
            Rules = new List<string> { "Rule1", "Rule2" },
            Results = new Result
            {
                ResultName = "ResultName1",
                Instances = new List<Instance>
                {
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V1"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name2", Value = "V2"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V3"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name4", Value = "V4"}
                        }
                    },
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V5"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name2", Value = "V6"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V7"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name4", Value = "V8"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

- This packet have more than one Name and I need to split it based on matching rule and name from `List<NameOwnersBasedOnRule>` and need to distribute the the associated owners.

For above data example packet I have 2 rules "Rule1", "Rule2", hence

- Name1 should be distributed to Owner1 and Owner2.
- Name2 only to Owner2.
- Name3 to all owners Owner1, Owner2, Owner3
- 'Name4` to NONE

Expected data for each owner should be like this,

```
var owner1Data = new Packet
        {
            Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
            Results = new Result
            {
                ResultName = "ResultName1",
                Instances = new List<Instance>
                {
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V1"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V3"}
                        }
                    },
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V5"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V7"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var owner2Data = new Packet
        {
            Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
            Results = new Result
            {
                ResultName = "ResultName1",
                Instances = new List<Instance>
                {
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V1"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name2", Value = "V2"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V3"}
                        }
                    },
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name1", Value = "V5"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name2", Value = "V6"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V7"},
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var owner3Data = new Packet
        {
            Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
            Results = new Result
            {
                ResultName = "ResultName1",
                Instances = new List<Instance>
                {
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V3"}
                        }
                    },
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "Name3", Value = "V7"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Here all the class structure I have,

```
public class NameOwnersBasedOnRule
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Owners { get; set; }
}

public class Packet
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Rules { get; set; }
    public Result Results { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string ResultName { get; set; }
    public List<Instance> Instances { get; set; }
}

public class Instance
{
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
    public List<InstanceData> InstanceDatas { get; set; }
}

public class InstanceData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Note -**

**This below method split my big `packet` by `Name`.**

```
private static IEnumerable<Packet> SplitByName(Packet packet)
    {
        var names = packet.Results.Instances
            .SelectMany(it => it.InstanceDatas)
            .Select(it => it.Name)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

        IList<Packet> result = new List<Packet>();

        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            var newInstances = packet.Results.Instances
                .Select(it => new Instance
                {
                    InstanceName = it.InstanceName,
                    InstanceDatas = it.InstanceDatas
                        .Where(it1 => it1.Name == name)
                        .ToList()
                })
                .Where(it => it.InstanceDatas.Any())
                .ToList();

            var newResult = new Result
            {
                ResultName = packet.Results.ResultName,
                Instances = newInstances
            };

            result.Add(new Packet
            {
                Id = packet.Id,
                Results = newResult
            });
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**Can we then prepare required result for each owner in one query?**

Comment: Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: I am trying @ Progman, getting all the distinct `Name` from `Packet` then after loop on names I am missing something on how to compare with `List<NameOwnersBasedOnRule>`

Comment: Please don't vote negative. The answer below works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
private Packet CreatePacket(string psOwner, Packet poSourcePacket, List<NameOwnersBasedOnRule> poRuleSet)
{
    //Create new Output Packet
    Packet loDestPacket = new Packet()
    {
        Id = poSourcePacket.Id,
        Results = new Result()
        {
            ResultName = poSourcePacket.Results.ResultName,
            Instances = new List<Instance>()
        }
    };

    //Create a simple List with valid Names for Owner and for all Rules in the Source
    IEnumerable<string> loList = poRuleSet
        .Where(item => item.Owners
            .Any(o => o.Value == psOwner && poSourcePacket.Rules.Contains(o.Key)))
        .Select(item => item.Name);

    //Add all Instance with InstanceData to the output Packet
    loDestPacket.Results.Instances.AddRange(poSourcePacket.Results.Instances
        .Where(item => item.InstanceDatas.Any(data => loList.Contains(data.Name)))
        .Select(item => new Instance()
        {
            InstanceName = item.InstanceName,
            InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>(item.InstanceDatas
                    .Where(data => loList.Contains(data.Name))
                    .Select(data => new InstanceData()
                    {
                        Name = data.Name,
                        Value = data.Value
                    }))
        }));

    return loDestPacket;
}
```

Call the method (for Owner1):

```
this.CreatePacket("Owner1", dataPacket, nameOwnersBasedOnRule);
```

Comment: Excellent @PinBack. Thanks and Appreciated. I have one extension question, if I have dynamic number of owner, could be 2, could be 3, then can we extend it and return return list of owners with associated data?

Comment: I need to call multiple time the method for different owner. Is possible to traverse one time and get all the data for all owner.  Thanks

Comment: You can first load all owners into a list and call the method in a loop. The result can be for example a `Dictionary<string, Packet>`

Comment: Yes. I can do loop on owner's, but I have max upto 10 owner's and 100 of packets to process per minute.  Iteration is too much. Thoughts?

Comment: Please check my Note in the question. If we split the packet by Name, then can we prepare the owner data in one go? Thanks for help.

Comment: Is there really a performance issue if you iterate over owners?

Comment: Yes. Both list has many items and sub items and iterating both list for each  packet is pain point